# Can pandas truncate my data and cause irreparable data loss without any kind of warning whatsoever?

Tags: python, pandas, floating-point, truncate

```
import pandas as pd
import io

indata = io.StringIO("c\n10000000000")

df = pd.read_csv(indata, header=0)
print(df)

indata.seek(0)

df = pd.read_csv(indata, header=0, dtype={"c":int})
print(df)
```

Expected Output:

```
             c
0  10000000000
            c
0  10000000000
```

Actual Output:

```
             c
0  10000000000
            c
0  1410065408
```

Can pandas truncate my data this way with no warning whatsoever?

I was banging my head trying to figure out why my script didn't work (of course this is a toy example. My script is more complicated). After 45 minutes of desperation (trying also to figure out the data type that pandas assigned to my columns) I just discovered the behaviour above.

I set the `dtype` in my real script because pandas was keeping loading that column as a `float` but I needed it as a `int` to make comparisons.

EDIT: Additional information as requested in the comments:

Python version

```
Python 3.8.5 (default, Sep  3 2020, 21:29:08) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)] :: Anaconda, Inc. on win32
```

Pandas version: 1.1.3

Platform:

```
>>> platform.platform()
'Windows-10-10.0.18362-SP0'
>>> platform.processor()
'Intel64 Family 6 Model 158 Stepping 10, GenuineIntel'
>>> platform.version()
'10.0.18362'
```

Comment: Works fine for me in pandas version ``'1.0.5'``

Comment: @sushanth maybe it's cause by the platform? I have conda with Python 3.8 on Windows 10 x64

Comment: @sushanth the only way to work for you I think is to have a 64-bit int by default ... which platform are you using?

Comment: printing `platform.platform()`, `platform.processor()` and maybe `platform.version()` would give more details.

Comment: Works fine for me too. my `pd.__version__`->`1.1.4`, ubuntu 20.04 focal fosa

Comment: @tdelaney I am running this exact script

Comment: @tdelaney I provided you the information you requested

Comment: Thanks for the update. It certainly clears up that this is not a 32 bit problem. I run ubuntu and the code works for me. I see nothing to explain this strange problem. Reinstall everything?

Comment: @tdelaney is it possible that I somehow ended up with the 32 bit version of Anaconda? Because in the first output it says `Anaconda, Inc. on win32` (the one I reported under "Python version")

Comment: The important part is `[MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)]` - python was compiled in 64 bit with Microsoft's C compiler. Back in the day,  Windows 3.x was 16 bits using segment:offset as pointers. When Microsoft moved to full 32 bit, its API had to change and it was called Win32. Turns out, the move from 32 to 64 could be transparent - the compiler figures it out (with some help from Windows on Windows and other tricks). Since the API didn't change, it kept the name Win32 even though its 64.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see what's happening here. From the [pandas documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html):

> dtypeType name or dict of column -> type, optional
> Data type for data or columns. E.g. `{‘a’: np.float64, ‘b’: np.int32, ‘c’: ‘Int64’}` Use `str` or `object` together with suitable `na_values` settings to preserve and not interpret dtype. If converters are specified, they will be applied INSTEAD of dtype conversion.

So, it is mentioned in CAPITAL LETTERS that `read_csv()` will use the dtype converter if you specify one. So, passing `int` is like explicitly telling it to use numpy equivalent of `int`. That is why there is no warnings, and it should be considered expected behavior.

---

**Now, the question is why my numpy equivalent of `int` is `int32` instead of `int64`?**

The numpy ([doc](https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/arrays.scalars.html#built-in-scalar-types)) maps python's `int` to built-in scalar `np.int_` with the following warning:

[image]

The [numpy documentation](https://numpy.org/devdocs/user/basics.types.html#array-types-and-conversions-between-types) specifies that the built-in scalar `np.int_` is platform dependent:

[image]

**TL;DR** `int(python) -> int_(numpy) -> long(C)`

So, the question is what does `long` mean for your system?

For MSC, `long` is 4 bytes as shown in the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/data-type-ranges):

[image]

and confirmed by numpy:

[image]

For GCC, `long` is 8 bytes as confirmed here:

[image]

---

Hope this was useful, and you learned something new.

Comment: I will read it more carefully afterwards, but still it is UNEXPLAINABLE TO ME why pandas to that silently ... I NEVER EXPECT IT to cut out and truncate my data and cause data loss silently